# Pandas lambda function... Faster computation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `dataframe` of `dates` and `codes`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': list(pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-12-30')) * 364,
     'code': np.random.permutation(list(np.arange(23001, 23001 + 8281)) * 16)}
).sort_values('date', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

What I would like is, for each `code` occurred at a `specific time`, count all identical `code` that happened before or at the same date.

```
def nb_code_at_date(x):
    condition = (df['date'] <= x['date'])
    return (df.loc[condition, 'code'] == x['code']).sum()
```

The issue is clearly the time needed to compute this for a 'large' dataframe:

```
%%timeit
df.head(1000).apply(lambda x: nb_code_at_date(x), axis=1)
>> 2.89 s ± 283 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

How would you deal to enhance this waiting time?

Comment: Can a code occur more than once on a day?

Comment: yes, it can occur

Comment: For each occurrence at a specific time, do all occurrences of the same code that are after it but on the same day need to be counted?

Comment: I consider here no difference in time, but only difference on dates. Thus the intra-day difference is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found is to use the pandas.crosstab function to compute a pre-defined dataframe, ready-to-use and fixed.

```
temp = pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['code'])

def nb_code_at_date2(x):
    condition = (temp.index <= x['date'])
    return (temp.loc[condition, x['code']]).sum()

%%timeit
df.head(1000).apply(lambda x: nb_code_at_date2(x), axis=1)
>>750 ms ± 73.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The task can be accomplished using [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount) and [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation):

```
output = df.join(df.groupby(["code"]).cumcount().add(1).to_frame())
output = output.groupby(["code", "date"]).transform("max")
```